# SQL-запрос на выборку из трёх таблиц с условием

Tags: mysql, sql

Я начинающий программист и ещё плохо разбираюсь в MySQL. Помогите, пожалуйста, с задачей:

Есть три таблицы: `trainee`, `history` и `course`.

```
trainee: (trainee_id; trainee_name; email)

course: (course_id; name; discription)

history: (history_id; trainee_id; course_id; start; end; status) (0 - отрицательное значение, 1 - положительное).
```

Первое условие звучит так:

Вывести список стажёров `trainee name, trainee email, course name, history end`, которые успешно окончили курс `РНР` (`course name` = `PHP`) в прошлом месяце (сравнить `history end`).

Пробовал запрос такой:

```
SELECT tr.trainee_name, tr.email, h.end, co.name
from trainee tr
inner join history h on tr.trainee_id=h.trainee_id and h.end BETWEEN "01.08.2018" AND "31.08.2018"
inner join course co on co.course_id=h.course_id
```

Comment: Что пробовали сделать? Что не получилось?

Comment: Не получается выполнить условие. Старался всячески изменить запросы, которые находил в интернете - но... в итоге выходили одни ошибки. Даже не знаю, что тут нужно сделать.

Comment: *Даже не знаю, что тут нужно сделать.* Надо писАть свой запрос, а не стараться изменить чужие.

Comment: Покажите что пробовали, на чем остановились.

Comment: Пробовал запрос такой:
SELECT tr.trainee_name, tr.email, h.end, co.name
from trainee tr
inner join history h
    on tr.trainee_id=h.trainee_id
    and h.end BETWEEN "01.08.2018" AND "31.08.2018"
inner join course co
    on co.course_id=h.course_id

Своих знаний же вовсе не хватает на создание запросов (могу только простенькие составить, вроде SELECT*FROM WHERE)

Comment: Правда... запрос конечно совсем не той тематики...

Comment: Отделите связывание таблиц (секция FROM, предложение JOIN..ON) от условий отбора (секция WHERE) из уже связанных таблиц.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `and status = 1` в условии выборки `WHERE` для того чтобы записи соответствовали "успешно окончили курс". Далее выводится список `id` этих записей, который можно использовать для выборки из основной таблицы подзапросом.

```
SELECT tr.id from trainee tr inner join history h on 
  tr.trainee_id=h.trainee_id  inner join course co on co.course_id=h.course_id 
WHERE h.end BETWEEN '01.08.2018 00:00:00' AND '31.08.2018 23:59:59' and h.status = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Получилось вот такое дело.

```
SELECT tr.trainee_name, tr.email, h.end, co.name
from trainee tr
inner join history h
    on tr.trainee_id=h.trainee_id
    and h.end BETWEEN "2018-08-01 00:00:00.00" AND "2018-09-01 00:00:00.00"
inner join course co
    on co.course_id=h.course_id AND h.status=1 AND h.course_id=3
```